# Is it important to remove swarm nodes?

Tags: iri-node, iota-network, node, nelson, swarmnodes

I use the iri in combination with field and nelson. I came into a synced status and then dropped the swarm nodes. Since then, the node often changes from "synced" to "unsynced" and back irregularly.

Why should I drop the swarm nodes? Can't I just leave one of those nodes active? Or where is the disadvantage?